# Definition of a norm on a vector space of sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I am slightly confused about normed vector spaces. I have been given that, for the normed vector space $\ell^p$ of sequences $\left(x_i\right)^{\infty}_{i=1}$, where $x_i\in\mathbb{C}$, with $\left(\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\left|x_i\right|^p\right)$ finite, the following expression defines a norm on $\ell^p$:
$$\lVert\left(x_i\right)\rVert:=\left(\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}|x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

How do I go about showing that this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show three things to show something is a norm, the first two are usually easy.

A:  That it is positive semidefinite,  aka,  $\|x\|\geq 0$ with equality if and only if $x=0$

B:  Scalar products distribute out as norms of the scalars,   ie $\|zx\|=|z|\|x\|$  where $z$ is a complex number, $x$ is a vector (here a sequence).

and C: The triangle inequality, the only one that usually takes much work, for any two vectors $x,y$,  $\|x+y\|\leq \|x+y\|$,  for this you usually need to use a well known inequality

Comment: You have an error in your triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The triangle inequality for the $l^p$ norm (or more generally, $L^p$ norms) is known as Minkowski's inequality. There are several proofs, many based on Holder's inequality. One approach for $p \in [1, \infty)$ is to show that Holder's inequality is strict in the sense that if $x \in l^p$,
$$\lVert x \rVert_{l^p} = \max\left\{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|x_n y_n| : y \in l^q, \lVert y \rVert_{l^q} = 1\right\},$$
where $q = \frac{p}{p - 1}$.
The triangle inequality then follows easily from this. To prove the above result, try $y$ of the form $y = Cx^{p - 1}$.